# jQuery How to reset previous opened dropdown after clicking another dropdown button

Tags: jquery, html

Would like to ask for help on my jquery. I've saw a bug regarding my drop-down button. When I open a drop-down button, it opens with a negative symbol as sign of dropdown menu but when I click another drop-down button, it also open with the same symbol but my previous doesn't reset to its normal form with positive symbol.

Here's a screenshot of what I meant.

[image]

Here'y my Codes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.dropdown-menu').not($(this).next('.dropdown-menu')).fadeOut()
        $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').fadeToggle().toggleClass('isOpen');


        if ($('.dropdown-menu').hasClass('isOpen')) {
            $(this).html("-"); 
            $(this).siblings('a').css("color", "#f37727");
            } else {
            $(this).html("+");
            $(this).siblings('a').css("color", "#000");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sdcollections-list">


      <li class="sdc-element">
        <a href="/collections/dogs">
          <div class="element-main">

            <div class="collection-area ">
              <div class="collection-name">
                Dogs 
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>



          <ul>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-beds-and-bedding" style="color: rgb(243, 119, 39);">Dog Beds &amp; Bedding</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">-</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu isOpen" style="display: none;">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/soft-dog-beds">Soft Dog Beds</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/mattress-dog-beds">Mattress Dog Beds</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/plastic-dog-beds-and-cushions">Plastic Dog Beds and Cushions</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/3-peaks">3 Peaks</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/luxury-dog-beds">Luxury Dog Beds</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-blankets">Dog Blankets</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/specific-dog-beds">Specific Dog Beds</a>
                                    </li>


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-coats-and-clothes" style="color: rgb(243, 119, 39);">Dog Coats &amp; Clothes</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">-</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu isOpen" style="display: block;">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-heating-and-cooling-beds">Dog Heating and Cooling Beds</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-cooling-and-calming">Dog Cooling and Calming</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-knitwear">Dog Knitwear</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-rainwear">Dog Rainwear</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-reflective-coats">Dog Reflective Coats</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-warmwear">Dog Warmwear</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/small-dog-coats">Small Dog Coats</a>
                                    </li>


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-collars">Dog Collars and Leads</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-collars">Dog Collars</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-leads">Dog Leads</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-extending-leads">Dog Extending Leads</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-tags-accessories">Dog Tags &amp; Accessories</a>
                                    </li>


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-flea-control-and-wormers">Dog Flea Control &amp; Wormers</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-flea-treatment">Dog Flea Treatment</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-wormers">Dog Wormers</a>
                                    </li>


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-grooming">Dog Grooming</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-clippers-and-scissors">Dog Clippers and Scissors</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-nail-clippers">Dog Nail Clippers</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-shampoo-conditioners">Dog Shampoo &amp; Conditioners</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-brushes-combs">Dog Brushes &amp; Combs</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-sprays-hygiene-products">Dog Sprays &amp; Hygiene Products</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-towels">Dog Towels</a>
                                    </li>


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-harness">Dog Harness</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-health-and-treatments">Dog Health &amp; Treatments</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-dental-care">Dog Dental Care</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-ear-care">Dog Ear Care</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-health-supplements">Dog Health Supplements</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-skin-and-creams">Dog Skin and Creams</a>
                                    </li>


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-kennels-and-flaps">Dog Kennels &amp; Flaps</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-kennels">Dog Kennels</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-pens">Dog Pens</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-flaps-and-gates">Dog Flaps and Gates</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-carriers">Dog Carriers</a>
                                    </li>


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-leads">Dog Leads</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-tags">Dog Tags</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-toys">Dog Toys</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/ball-and-outdoor">Ball and Outdoor</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/brain-games">Brain Games</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-chews">Dog Chews</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-novelty-toys">Dog Novelty Toys</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-top-toys">Dog Top Toys</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/toys-for-puppys">Toys For Puppys</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-soft-toys">Dog Soft Toys</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-tougher-toys">Dog Tougher Toys</a>
                                    </li>


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-training">Dog Training</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-anti-bark-accessories">Dog Anti-Bark Accessories</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-muzzles">Dog Muzzles</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-clicker-and-whistle-training">Dog Clicker And Whistle Training</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-chewing-solutions">Dog Chewing Solutions</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-toilet-training">Dog Toilet Training</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-agility-training">Dog Agility Training</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/other-training-solutions">Other Training Solutions</a>
                                    </li>


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-travel">Dog Travel</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/puppy-products">Puppy Products</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

          </ul>

      </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: share your html code

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai added my html.

Comment: so initially you kept open so many menu's and then if someone  press some button then you want hide all the other menu and only open the current one with `-` symbol and remaining should have `+` symbol. is that functionality you are expecting?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai yes correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the logic is simple. Initially you want to show some menu's in open status. So you have to keep the `isOpen` class for the particular list items and keep the symbol `-` for the buttons and apply the color code for the `a`. Through CSS, try to apply the `display` properties like if the list items have the class `isOpen` then make it `display:block` othewise `display:none` like below.

```
 .dropdown-menu {
     display:none;
 }
 .dropdown-menu.isOpen {
     display:block;
 }
```

Now if you click some button, you have to remove the `isOpen` class from the other list items and keep this class only for the current list items. Also you have to make the button `+` for others and `-` for the current. For links you have to apply different color for the current one and keep default one for the remaining. This you can achieve using the following code.

```
  $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.dropdown-menu').not($(this).next('.dropdown-menu')).fadeOut();
    $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('isOpen');
    $('.dropdown-menu').siblings('button').html("+");
    $('.dropdown-menu').siblings('a').css("color", "#000");
    $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').fadeToggle().addClass('isOpen');
    $(this).html("-");
    $(this).siblings('a').css("color", "#f37727");
  });
```

**EDIT**

The above will fail in one scenario like if you click the same button again then it is showing the wrong `-` button symbol and the wrong color code of `a` tag. For fix that I am checking the current status then updating the style of the current element like below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var close = $(this).html() == "-" ? false : true;
    $('.dropdown-menu').not($(this).next('.dropdown-menu')).fadeOut();
    $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').fadeToggle();
    $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('isOpen');
    $('.dropdown-menu').siblings('button').html("+");
    $('.dropdown-menu').siblings('a').css("color", "#000");        
    if(close) {
      $(this).html("-");
      $(this).siblings('a').css("color", "#f37727");
    }        
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display:none;
}
.dropdown-menu.isOpen {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sdcollections-list">


      <li class="sdc-element">
        <a href="/collections/dogs">
          <div class="element-main">

            <div class="collection-area ">
              <div class="collection-name">
                Dogs 
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>



          <ul>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-beds-and-bedding" style="color: rgb(243, 119, 39);">Dog Beds &amp; Bedding</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">-</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu isOpen">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/soft-dog-beds">Soft Dog Beds</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/mattress-dog-beds">Mattress Dog Beds</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/plastic-dog-beds-and-cushions">Plastic Dog Beds and Cushions</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/3-peaks">3 Peaks</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/luxury-dog-beds">Luxury Dog Beds</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-blankets">Dog Blankets</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/specific-dog-beds">Specific Dog Beds</a>
                                    </li>
                            
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-coats-and-clothes" style="color: rgb(243, 119, 39);">Dog Coats &amp; Clothes</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">-</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu isOpen">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-heating-and-cooling-beds">Dog Heating and Cooling Beds</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-cooling-and-calming">Dog Cooling and Calming</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-knitwear">Dog Knitwear</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-rainwear">Dog Rainwear</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-reflective-coats">Dog Reflective Coats</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-warmwear">Dog Warmwear</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/small-dog-coats">Small Dog Coats</a>
                                    </li>
                           
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-collars">Dog Collars and Leads</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-collars">Dog Collars</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-leads">Dog Leads</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-extending-leads">Dog Extending Leads</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-tags-accessories">Dog Tags &amp; Accessories</a>
                                    </li>

                           
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-flea-control-and-wormers">Dog Flea Control &amp; Wormers</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-flea-treatment">Dog Flea Treatment</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-wormers">Dog Wormers</a>
                                    </li>

                           
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-grooming">Dog Grooming</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-clippers-and-scissors">Dog Clippers and Scissors</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-nail-clippers">Dog Nail Clippers</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-shampoo-conditioners">Dog Shampoo &amp; Conditioners</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-brushes-combs">Dog Brushes &amp; Combs</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-sprays-hygiene-products">Dog Sprays &amp; Hygiene Products</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-towels">Dog Towels</a>
                                    </li>
                         
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-harness">Dog Harness</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-health-and-treatments" style="color: rgb(243, 119, 39);">Dog Health &amp; Treatments</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">-</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu isOpen">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-dental-care">Dog Dental Care</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-ear-care">Dog Ear Care</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-health-supplements">Dog Health Supplements</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-skin-and-creams">Dog Skin and Creams</a>
                                    </li>
                           
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-kennels-and-flaps">Dog Kennels &amp; Flaps</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-kennels">Dog Kennels</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-pens">Dog Pens</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-flaps-and-gates">Dog Flaps and Gates</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-carriers">Dog Carriers</a>
                                    </li>
                             
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-leads">Dog Leads</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-tags">Dog Tags</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                             
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-toys">Dog Toys</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/ball-and-outdoor">Ball and Outdoor</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/brain-games">Brain Games</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-chews">Dog Chews</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-novelty-toys">Dog Novelty Toys</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-top-toys">Dog Top Toys</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/toys-for-puppys">Toys For Puppys</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-soft-toys">Dog Soft Toys</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-tougher-toys">Dog Tougher Toys</a>
                                    </li>

                          
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-training">Dog Training</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-anti-bark-accessories">Dog Anti-Bark Accessories</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-muzzles">Dog Muzzles</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-clicker-and-whistle-training">Dog Clicker And Whistle Training</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-chewing-solutions">Dog Chewing Solutions</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-toilet-training">Dog Toilet Training</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-agility-training">Dog Agility Training</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/other-training-solutions">Other Training Solutions</a>
                                    </li>
                             
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-travel">Dog Travel</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                              
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/puppy-products">Puppy Products</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                         
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

          </ul>

      </li>
</ul>
```

If you are looking for the fiddle version demo, then [**Here you go.**](https://jsfiddle.net/h917zcoa/49/)

Comment: Suresh - the code is working but there's another bug. When I click the dropdown button back, the symbol is negative. You added solution but it affects the existing function.

Comment: didn't understand the problem. which existing function it is affected?

Comment: ya i got that problem...let me check it out.

Comment: i have fixed that one. check the updated answer and snippet/fiddle.

Comment: Suresh - you're amazing! thank you so much for helping me solved this issue! God bless you!

Comment: Thanks for your blessings.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a $.each loop on `.dropdown-menu` instead of just a singular `hasClass` check , see below code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.dropdown-menu').not($(this).next('.dropdown-menu')).fadeOut()
        $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').fadeToggle().toggleClass('isOpen');

        $('.dropdown-menu').each(function(){
            if($(this)..hasClass('isOpen')) {
                $(this).html("-").siblings('a').css("color", "#f37727");
            } else {
                $(this).html("+").siblings('a').css("color", "#000");        
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Below is the newly added code:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('isOpen')) {
            $(this).html("-").siblings('a').css("color", "#f37727");
        } else {
            $(this).html("+").siblings('a').css("color", "#000");        
        }
 });
```

Comment: Alexander - I tried to remove the additional dot on hasClass but still not working. the sub menus disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

you are really near to it. but i think you just forgot this line

`if($(this).hasClass('isOpen'))`

`dropdown-menu` never have class `isOpen`. the next element is the one which have it. so the correct script is :

`if($(this).next().hasClass('isOpen'))`

here your fiddle after fixed

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.dropdown-menu').not($(this).next('.dropdown-menu')).fadeOut()
        $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').fadeToggle().toggleClass('isOpen');
var parentLi = $(this).closest('li');
if ($(this).next('.dropdown-menu').hasClass('isOpen')) {
            $(this).html("-"); 
            $(this).siblings('a').css("color", "#f37727");
            } else {
            $(this).html("+");
            $(this).siblings('a').css("color", "#000");
        }
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sdcollections-list">


      <li class="sdc-element">
        <a href="/collections/dogs">
          <div class="element-main">

            <div class="collection-area ">
              <div class="collection-name">
                Dogs 
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>



          <ul>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-beds-and-bedding" style="color: rgb(243, 119, 39);">Dog Beds &amp; Bedding</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/soft-dog-beds">Soft Dog Beds</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/mattress-dog-beds">Mattress Dog Beds</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/plastic-dog-beds-and-cushions">Plastic Dog Beds and Cushions</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/3-peaks">3 Peaks</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/luxury-dog-beds">Luxury Dog Beds</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-blankets">Dog Blankets</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/specific-dog-beds">Specific Dog Beds</a>
                                    </li>


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-coats-and-clothes" style="color: rgb(243, 119, 39);">Dog Coats &amp; Clothes</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">-</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu isOpen" style="display: block;">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-heating-and-cooling-beds">Dog Heating and Cooling Beds</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-cooling-and-calming">Dog Cooling and Calming</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-knitwear">Dog Knitwear</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-rainwear">Dog Rainwear</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-reflective-coats">Dog Reflective Coats</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-warmwear">Dog Warmwear</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/small-dog-coats">Small Dog Coats</a>
                                    </li>


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-collars">Dog Collars and Leads</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-collars">Dog Collars</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-leads">Dog Leads</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-extending-leads">Dog Extending Leads</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-tags-accessories">Dog Tags &amp; Accessories</a>
                                    </li>


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-flea-control-and-wormers">Dog Flea Control &amp; Wormers</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-flea-treatment">Dog Flea Treatment</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-wormers">Dog Wormers</a>
                                    </li>


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-grooming">Dog Grooming</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-clippers-and-scissors">Dog Clippers and Scissors</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-nail-clippers">Dog Nail Clippers</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-shampoo-conditioners">Dog Shampoo &amp; Conditioners</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-brushes-combs">Dog Brushes &amp; Combs</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-sprays-hygiene-products">Dog Sprays &amp; Hygiene Products</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-towels">Dog Towels</a>
                                    </li>


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-harness">Dog Harness</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-health-and-treatments">Dog Health &amp; Treatments</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-dental-care">Dog Dental Care</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-ear-care">Dog Ear Care</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-health-supplements">Dog Health Supplements</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-skin-and-creams">Dog Skin and Creams</a>
                                    </li>


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-kennels-and-flaps">Dog Kennels &amp; Flaps</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-kennels">Dog Kennels</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-pens">Dog Pens</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-flaps-and-gates">Dog Flaps and Gates</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-carriers">Dog Carriers</a>
                                    </li>


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-leads">Dog Leads</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-tags">Dog Tags</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-toys">Dog Toys</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/ball-and-outdoor">Ball and Outdoor</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/brain-games">Brain Games</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-chews">Dog Chews</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-novelty-toys">Dog Novelty Toys</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-top-toys">Dog Top Toys</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/toys-for-puppys">Toys For Puppys</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-soft-toys">Dog Soft Toys</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-tougher-toys">Dog Tougher Toys</a>
                                    </li>


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-training">Dog Training</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-anti-bark-accessories">Dog Anti-Bark Accessories</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-muzzles">Dog Muzzles</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-clicker-and-whistle-training">Dog Clicker And Whistle Training</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-chewing-solutions">Dog Chewing Solutions</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-toilet-training">Dog Toilet Training</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/dog-agility-training">Dog Agility Training</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li">
                                        <a href="/collections/other-training-solutions">Other Training Solutions</a>
                                    </li>


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/dog-travel">Dog Travel</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

            <li class="list-unstyled nav-sub-mega">
              <a href="/collections/puppy-products">Puppy Products</a> 
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">+</button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">


                                    <!--<li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Mattress Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Plastic Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">3 Peaks</a></li>    
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Dog Blankets</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Heating Dog Beds</a></li>   
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Specific Dog Beds</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-menu-li"><a href="">Luxury Dog Bed</a></li>-->                                  
                                </ul>                                   
            </li>

          </ul>

      </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: plonknimbuzz - the code is not working. still the same issue I had. I've run code snippet your code.